# How can I open a web page in App Inventor

Tags: android, mobile-application, app-inventor

I have a webviewer which is the main application andbelow the webviewer is a button. I would like to open a web page in the user's web browser when the button it clicked. How can I do this in App Inventor?

```
Action: android.intent.action.VIEW 
DataUri: http://example.com
```

The above as instructed in the documentation isn't working.

Comment: Do you want to oppen http://example.com in browser if the button is clicked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add ActivityStarter to the screen and configure its properties:

```
ActivityStarter1
Action:android.intent.action.VIEW
DataUri:http://example.com
```

Leave the other properties empty.

[image]

On the same screen, configure the event handler of the button to call the activityStarter1.StartActivity:

[image]

By pressing the button, the web browser is opened with the page http://example.com

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!! One more question. I know about the webView problem so a tel: link won't open the phonecall option.
In the browser, when I set the link to tel://555-5555 and the user clicks it, the dial pad would pop up but it's not like this in webView(read the reason online) but how can I get it to work in App Inventor?
Also, is it possible to have file input(<input type="file">) to work from webView in App Inventor? Couldn't get it t work in Android Studio. API not public but followed some tutorials but still didn't works. New to this, could use your assistance. Thanks for your help again :

Comment: For calling, use the PhoneCall object.

Answer (score -1):

use the activity starter with the action `android.intent.action.VIEW`

The `data URI` is the website you want to open.

Then use:

```
call ActivityStarter1.StartActivity
```

Comment: well, that's actually a copy of @MirecXP's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28879649/1545993) from 2015, only your answer is not as detailed, which means, your answer does not help very much... you might want to focus on new questions instead...