# How can I call a web page in App Inventor?

Tags: android, app-inventor

I made a PHP code which will turn off and on led.
http://x.x.x.xx/va.php?on=ON (LED will turn on)
http://x.x.x.xx/va.php?off=OFF (LED will turn off)

and also two buttons for ON and OFF in App Inventor.

This link [How can I open a web page in App Inventor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28869954/how-can-i-open-a-web-page-in-app-inventor) shows perfect solution on how to open a web page.

**But** what I want is whenever I click ON, it will call the PHP without go to the PHP page directly. How to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Don't know app-inventor but in Android, you should look at HttpUrlConnection to call this URL. Might be something similar there. What you want is send a request to your server. The link you provide show how to send an action to open a other app. This could work but this is not as user friendly

Comment: oh..okk.  I will check it out.Thank you for your reply @AxelH .  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.
I solved it by simply referring on youtube.
[image: Here is the blocks that should be put in App Inventor.]